# Ninja with cl -showIncludes, reducing the volume of output

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ninja

I'm using ninja to build a C++ project on Windows. Correctly specifying header dependencies is a hard problem, and happily ninja has a feature where it will cooperate with the compiler in doing this automatically. So following the advice in the manual, I have this in my build file:

```
msvc_deps_prefix=Note: including file:
rule cc
 deps=msvc
 command=cl -EHsc -nologo -showIncludes -std:c++20 -MDd -W2 -WX -DPOSTGRES $ipath $in -c
```

And it does actually seem to work! I change a header file, and modules that include it, get recompiled.

The problem is that ninja doesn't just use the `showIncludes` output for that purpose, it also dumps it to the terminal. The upshot is that the terminal gets flooded with tens of screenfuls of

```
Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um\ole2.h
Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared\pshpack8.h
Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um\objbase.h
Note: including file:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared\pshpack8.h
Note: including file:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um\combaseapi.h
Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared\pshpack8.h
Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um\unknwnbase.h
Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um\objidlbase.h
Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared\guiddef.h
Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um\cguid.h
Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared\poppack.h
```

etc, etc. Which, apart from being annoying, on a more practical level, makes it very difficult to pick out any of the useful information about what's going on.

Is there a way to make ninja not do this? `--quiet` doesn't help.

Comment: Pipe the output through `grep`, with a suitable pattern to strip out the lines you don't want?

Comment: @PaulSanders Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. `ninja -C bin --quiet|rg -w error^|warning^|FAILED`. Feels counterintuitive, but seems to work.